# ReactJS - How to detect when cancel is clicked on file input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file, event-handling

I want an event or get notified when the user clicks on the *cross icon* or the *cancel button* on the fileInput dialog so that I can perform some task based on this.

The **onChange** event is only triggered when the user clicks on *Open* Button.

Is there a way to get notified when the user clicks on a *cross icon* or *cancel button* using ReactJS?

[image]

Below is the working code snippet.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.fileInputClicked = this.fileInputClicked.bind(this);
  }
  
  fileInputClicked(event){
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log("File is Selected", file);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Hello world</p>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.fileInputClicked}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this is probably what I would do but I don't really like it, also I think that the whole idea of performing something because the user decided not to upload a file isn't a good user experience so use it wisely.

```
fileInputClicked(event){
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log("File is Selected", file);
        window.removeEventListener('focus', this.handleFocusBack);
}

handleFocusBack(){
    console.log('focus-back');
    window.removeEventListener('focus', this.handleFocusBack);
}

clickedFileInput(){
    window.addEventListener('focus', this.handleFocusBack);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>Hello world</p>
                <input onClick={this.clickedFileInput} type="file" onChange={this.fileInputClicked}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This way, when the user decides to close the file input, he focuses back on the window and you get the `handleFocusBack` functionality you want and when he adds a file he goes to the `fileInputClicked`.

Afaik, there is no 'out of the box' mechanism to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I needed an answer for it, too. However, the solution is slightly more complex than @Matan-Bobi suggests.

- The `click` event is triggered when the Browse button is clicked, *before* the File Dialog opens.
- The `focus` event is triggered *after* the File Dialog is closed, in both cases. That is, it is triggered by a click *either* on the Open button *or* on the Cancel button in the File Dialog.
- The `change` event is triggered a few milliseconds *after* the Open button is clicked. It is never triggered if the Cancel button is clicked.

Therefore, to detect if the Cancel button was clicked, you must wait *a few more milliseconds* to be sure that no `change` event has been triggered. In my tests, 100 milliseconds seems to be a good length of time to wait.

My code below provides Too Much Information (especially if you uncomment the line in the `componentDidUpdate` method), but it allows you to see all the hoops that need to be jumped through.

```js
const CANCEL_DELAY = 100;
let render = 0;


class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      feedback: "Browse for a file...",
      filename: "",
      timeOut: 0
    };

    this.dialogOpened = this.dialogOpened.bind(this);
    this.dialogClosed = this.dialogClosed.bind(this);
    this.fileSelected = this.fileSelected.bind(this);
    this.cancelDialog = this.cancelDialog.bind(this);
  }
  
  
  dialogOpened() {
    console.log("Dialog opened");
    window.addEventListener('focus', this.dialogClosed, { once: true});
    this.setState(() => ({ filename: "" }));
  }
  
  
  dialogClosed() {
    console.log("Dialog closed");
    console.time("closed_after");

    const timeOut = setTimeout(this.cancelDialog, CANCEL_DELAY);
    console.log(`timeOut ${timeOut} created`);

    this.setState(() => ({
      feedback: 'Dialog closed',
      timeOut
    }));
  }
  
  
  fileSelected() {
    console.timeEnd("closed_after"); // <25 ms on my computer

    const file = event.target.files[0];
    
    this.setState(() => ({
      feedback: `File was selected`,
      filename: file.name
    }));

    // TODO: Do something with the selected file
    console.log(`+++ File: ${file.name} selected +++`);

    this.destroyTimeout();
  }
  
  
  cancelDialog() {
    console.log(`cancelDialog triggered after ${CANCEL_DELAY} ms`);
    console.timeEnd("closed_after");
    this.setState(() => ({ feedback: "Dialog was cancelled" }));
    // TODO: Do something about the cancellation
    console.log("--- File dialog was cancelled ---");
    this.destroyTimeout(); // > 103 ms
  }


  destroyTimeout() {
    console.log(`timeout ${this.state.timeOut} destroyed (${this.state.feedback})
    `);
    clearTimeout(this.state.timeOut);
    this.setState(() => ({ timeOut: 0 }));
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.feedback}</p>
        <input type="file"
          onClick={this.dialogOpened}
          onChange={this.fileSelected}
        />
        <p>{this.state.filename}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }


  componentDidUpdate() {
    // // Uncomment for more feedback
    // console.log(`Update ${++render}) updated state:`, this.state);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way is to verify your files array if empty or not.

The cancel event means that the user has not select any file which means :

> event.target.files.length = 0

```
const onFileChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.files.length ===0) {
      setFile(null); // undefined take place instead by default
      // the cancel event logics will always land here
    }
    else{
      setResume(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
```